# how can I solve this error in c++: Exception Unhandled?

Tags: biomedical-engineering

I am new in learning C++. I have used this code to show an image, but there is an error that I do not understand!

This is the simple code:

include iostream

include conio.h

include opencv2/core.hpp

include opencv2/highgui.hpp

include opencv2/opencv.hpp

include opencv2/imgproc.hpp

using namespace cv;

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

```
Mat img = imread("lena.jpg");

namedWindow("input image", WINDOW_NORMAL);

imshow("image", img);

waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

}

[image]

when I run, system.cpp will open and "Exception Unhandled" will be apear!!!
here is a picture of that, may you help please!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a software or coding stack.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This question seems more relevant to [SO].

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution!
I did these three steps and everything is ok now!

1)  I restored my system through: start/create a restore point/ system protection/ system restore/next/next...

2) I work with visual studio 2019 and I have two kind of libraries: v14 and v15, so I add both directories into the libraries direction

3) copy my code to new project!!

after these steps, the code works properly :D

Comment: If you accept this answer to close out the question, that would be great!